# Orthogonal basis in R3 containing a given set

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, orthogonality

I need guidance in solving this problem: Find an orthogonal basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ containing the set $S = \{v_1, v_2\}$ where $v_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
                -4 \\
                1 \\
                2
            \end{bmatrix}$ and  $v_2 = 
            \begin{bmatrix}
                0 \\
                -1 \\
                2
            \end{bmatrix}, \langle v_1, v_2\rangle := a_1b_1 + 4a_2b_2 + a_3b_3$

My approach:
Applying the Gram-Schmidt Method,
\begin{align*}
                x_1 &= v_1\\
                x_2 &= v_2 - \dfrac{{v_2}^Tx_1}{{x_1}^Tx_1}x_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
                0 \\
                -1 \\
                2
            \end{bmatrix}  - \dfrac{\begin{bmatrix}
                0 & -1 & 2
            \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
                -4 \\
                1 \\
                2
            \end{bmatrix}}{\begin{bmatrix}
                -4 & 1 & 2
            \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
                -4 \\
                1 \\
                2
            \end{bmatrix}}\begin{bmatrix}
                -4 \\
                1 \\
                2
            \end{bmatrix}\\
            &= \begin{bmatrix}
                0 \\
                -1 \\
                2
            \end{bmatrix} - \dfrac{3}{21}\begin{bmatrix}
                -4 \\
                1 \\
                2
            \end{bmatrix}\\
            &= \begin{bmatrix}
                0 \\
                -1 \\
                2
            \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix}
                -4/7 \\
                1/7 \\
                2/7
            \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
                4/7 \\
                -8/7 \\
                12/7
            \end{bmatrix}\\\\
            \text{Orthogonal basis } &= \text{ span}\left\{x_1, x_2\right\}\\
            &= \text{ span}\left\{\begin{bmatrix}
                -4 \\
                1 \\
                2
            \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
                4/7 \\
                -8/7 \\
                12/7
            \end{bmatrix}\right\}
            \end{align*}
Is my solution and conclusion correct?

Comment: can 2 vectors span $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: This was given as a seatwork for us which makes me wonder, could this possibly be a trick question?

Comment: Are you sure there is no accidental swapping of $y$ and $z$ coordinate for one of the two given vectors?

Comment: Do you know what the cross product (or: vector product) of vectors is ?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen those were the given. There was also an inner product endowed but I am not exactly sure where to use it. Updated my post.

Comment: @muw It is not a trick question. I was just pointing out that you needed one more vector!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With respect to the given inner product, you have $\langle v_1,v_2\rangle=0$; in other words, they're orthogonal.

So, find a vector$$u=\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}$$which is orthogonal to both and which os not the null vector. That is, solve the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}\langle v_1,u\rangle=0\\\langle v_2,u\rangle=0.\end{array}\right.$$Every solution is of the form$$u=\begin{bmatrix}2c\\c\\2c\end{bmatrix}$$and you can take, say,$$u=\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\\2\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: There is an endowed inner product, please see my updated post.

Comment: They are orthogonal w.r.t. given dot product.

Comment: @muw I've edited my answer.

Comment: @Yalikesifulei The “given dot product” was **not** given in the original version of the question. Actually, no mention was made to the fact there was *some* non-standard dot product involved.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos ok, sorry, I've seen the question with dot product already given :)

Comment: I'm sorry, how did u get $u = \begin{bmatrix}
                    c \\
                    2 \\
                    c
                \end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: Shouldn't $b = \dfrac{1}{2}$?

Comment: What I got was not that; it was $u=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}c\\2c\\c\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. And I got it by solving the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}\langle v_1,u\rangle=0\\\langle v_2,u\rangle=0,\end{array}\right.$$which is equivalent to$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}-4a+b+2c=0\\-b+2c=0.\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: Why should $b$ be $\frac12$?

Comment: $\langle v_1, u\rangle = (-4)(a) + 4(1)(b) + 2(c) \Rightarrow -4a + 4b + 2c$, $\langle v_2, u\rangle = 0(a) + 4(-1)(b) + 2(c) \Rightarrow -4b+2c$

Comment: @muw That's how I got the system.

Comment: Then, equating both to each other, we get $-4a + 8b$, if we let $a = 1$ which is the same in your case, then $b = \dfrac{1}{2}$, and then since $b = \dfrac{1}{2}$, $-4(1/2) + 2c \Rightarrow c = 1$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124441/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-muw).

Comment: In your system, $b = 1, -1$, which is not the case in my system where $b = 4, -4$.